# POST Varibles return null value in login api for opencart

Tags: php, api, post, opencart

On generating the api's for android application on open-cart framework PHP. I am trying to implement the login functionality as follows :

```
class ControllerApiLogin extends Controller {

  public function index() {

    $this->load->language('api/login');
    $this->load->model('account/api');

    if(($uid=$_GET['uid']) && ($otp= $_GET['otp'])){
    $api_info = $this->model_account_api->login($uid,$otp);
    if ($api_info) {

        $json['uid'] = $api_info['api_id'];
        $json['success'] = 1 ;
        $json['messsage'] = 'mobile number successfully verified';

    } else {

        $json['success'] = 0 ;
        $json['messsage'] = 'otp doesnot match with this user';

    }
    $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');

    $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
    }elseif($email = $_GET['email']){
        $name =  $_GET['name'];
        $api_info = $this->model_account_api->emaillogin($email,$name);
    if ($api_info) {

        $json['uid'] = $api_info['api_id'];
        $json['email'] = $api_info['email'];
        $json['name'] = $api_info['name'];
        $json['success'] = 1;
        $json['messsage'] = 'mobile number successfully verified';

    } else {

        $json['success'] = 0 ;
        $json['messsage'] = 'email does not match';

    }
    $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
    $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));

        }
        else{

        $json['success'] = 0;
        $json['message'] = 'otp not found';

        }
  }

}
```

In the above code I get NULL value when i try to get the data via POST method however this seems to work fine with GET method.I have checked even by sending static data in the POST method but still the problem persists however the same POST method seems to work fine with the following code:

```
class ControllerApiOtp extends Controller {

public function index() {
    $this->load->language('api/login');

        if(isset($_POST['generate'])){
            $otp = mt_rand('1000','9999');
            $mobile = $this->request->post['mobile'];

            $this->load->model('account/api');
            $api_info = $this->model_account_api->otplogin($otp,$mobile);

                if ($api_info) {

                    $json['uid'] = $api_info['api_id'];
                    $json['success'] = 1 /*$this->language->get('success_1')*/;
                    $json['messsage'] = $this->language->get('success_1');
                } else {

                    $json['success'] = 0 /*$this->language->get('error_insert')*/;
                    $json['messsage'] = $this->language->get('error_insert');
                }

            $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
            $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
        }

  }
}
```

Unable to track the issue some help is greatly appreciated .

Comment: response is coming null??

Comment: yes I get null even on sending static values !!